# whenever smooth vertex is pressed it breaks up mirrored objects

Tags: mirror

whenever smoth vertex is presssed it breaks up mirrored objects and i dont know why could somebody help please? i have tried: using diffrent axis,re-building the whole thing and others. please help. Result After Using Smooth Vertex:[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE!  Have you tried enabling *Clipping* on the mirror modifier?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to use the smooth vertex tool in this case? (it will only shrink the mesh but doesn't really smooth it due to it simplicity). Might want to try adding a Subdivision Surface Modifier instead (https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html)

Comment: also, putting only the result "after" doesn't say much about how it was "before"...

Answer (score 4):

You are doing this:

Cutting a cube and sticking a *Mirror Modifier* on it.

[image]

Then doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and picking 'Smooth Vertex'

[image]

This produces exactly what you show, and that's exactly what we would expect.

[image]

[*Smooth Vertex*](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html?highlight=smooth%20vertex#smooth) tries to pull all real vertices together. As mentioned in the docs

> This will apply once the [Smooth Tool](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/deforming/smooth.html).

You must remember you are performing this *Vertex* operation on only half a cube, (the rest is mirrored) and therefor the real center of all these real vertices (shaded in orange) lies within their collective coordinates, not on the mirror axis - the mirrored portion is not taken into account.

Objects with a bit more definition tend to smooth much more subtle, retaining much of the silhouette and scale.

[image]

I think your main confusion was that you where performing this operation on an object that relies on a Mirror Modifier for half of it's visual geometry. Maybe you are looking for the *Laplacian Smooth* deform modifier. (which will work ontop of the Mirror Modifier)

[image]

Or perhaps the *Subdivision Surface Modifier*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using clipping option in the mirror modifier.

Vertices on the mirror plane will be unable to move away from the mirror plane as long as Clipping is enabled.

[quoted from blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html)

> If it is enabled but vertices are beyond the mirror plane and outside of the Merge Distance, the vertices will not be merged. But as soon as the vertices are within Merge Distance they are snapped together and cannot be moved beyond the mirror plane.

Comment: Write about effectsit gives.